# Whenever i try to edit a file in nano it just makes a .swp file

Tags: linux, bash, nano

When i try to edit a file that already exists, it makes a new one that ends with `.swp`. I'm not very good at explaining but for example lets say i try to edit a file called "testfile.txt"
`nano testfile.txt`
then the file name will be `testfile.txt.swp` instead of `testfile.txt`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How do you exit `nano`?

Comment: just press ctrl + x

Comment: Step one might be: check `man nano`  @ FILES, and also `man nanorc` - verify sane contents in the files that exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal— when nano opens a file that is open in another process, it creates this so that, in case something goes *kerplunk* it can recover it.

> SWP files are created immediately when a Vi text editing session is started. They are saved to the same directory as their original file. For example, a text file with the name example.txt would have a swap file named .example.txt.swp.

from: https://fileinfo.com/extension/swp